# Are Powerpoint 2019 documents forwards compatible with Powerpoint 2016?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Does anyone know if Powerpoint 2019 documents are forwards compatible with Powerpoint 2016?

I know there were a pile of new features added in the new version, but I'm unsure if they are just creation tools or if they are required for display as well.

What it is is that I have a new departmental manager who wants to use 2019, but the rest of the company is on 2016, so I don't want to set him up with software that will cause compatibility issues if others try to view his Powerpoint presentations on their machines. My thinking is that is "should be" okay. But I've been wrong before because I used common sense

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if you are able to create a PowerPoint presentation with a feature that is supported by PowerPoint 2019 if it will also work with PowerPoint 2016?

Comment: I'm not asking if the features will work, obviously not, but if the document will display properly in the older versions after being created using the new features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PowerPoint encounters a feature it doesn't support (e.g. something created in 2019 that's not supported in 2016 or earlier), it doesn't just fall over and die. It either "gracefully degrades" or, if that's not possible, ignores it.

For example, if you add Morph transitions between slides in 2019, it'll turn into a fade transition in earlier versions that don't have Morph.

So basically you're in a "No worries" situation. Make the boss happy, BE happy.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, PowerPoint 2019 has a good compatibility with PowerPoint 2016. You can [use compatibility mode to work with different versions of PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-compatibility-mode-to-work-with-different-versions-of-powerpoint-bc87ca23-4208-4d58-9c01-3a38a84c16e0).

Even if you don’t have the latest version of PowerPoint, you can open and work with an older PowerPoint file. If you do have the latest version, compatibility mode makes it possible to work with the older file formats, too. You can also Run Compatibility Checker to ensure that your presentation does not have compatibility issues, and if you no longer need compatibility with earlier versions of PowerPoint, you can convert a presentation to the current file type.

For more information about compatibility mode, see [About compatibility mode in PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-compatibility-mode-in-powerpoint-aa6983bb-7858-40c5-bcc8-756faa7d29b0).

[image]

PowerPoint 2019 includes several new features that aren't available in prior versions. See:[What's new in PowerPoint 2019 for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-new-in-powerpoint-2019-for-windows-8355a56a-f643-42d2-8454-784fa9b3d109?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US).

Comment: My question is about forwards compatibility I guess, the thread title is wrong and I'll change that now. ie:opening and displaying files created with a newer version.
All of the information you provided is easily available but I am not finding the answer to my question.

Comment: John, you're saying this isn't what you asked, but looking at the current version of your question this is exactly what you asked. Either edit your question to clarify, or read the answer more carefully.

Comment: Steve Rindsberg grasped the question and gave me the answer..

Comment: Just to clarify things a bit (I hope): Compatibility mode assumes that you'll save your 2007 and later presentation to the earlier PPT/binary vs PPTX/zipped xml format. In @JohnScott's case, the issue in question is PPT 2019 vs PPT 2016 compatibility, which the checker doesn't address.